# If record exists then map, if not map another - Biztalk mapping

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper

Can someone help me with this?
I have a biztalk mapping. In the source scheme there are two address records with address elements.
Address record 1 always exists in the source scheme, but if address record 2 exists in the source I would like to map that to the destination instead of address record 1.
Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These are the steps I would take to achieve this - it'll have to be a high level description of a solution as you haven't included any schema definition or Xml sample.

You can use XSLT or The Mapping Designer to do this. I describe the latter;

1) Use the `Logical Existence` Functoid to Check if the Address 2 node exists. It return True if Address 2 is present in your source schema.

2) Connect the `Logical Existence` functoid to a `Value Mapping` functoid (as the first input) and drag the Address 2 value to the same (as your second input).

3) Connect the `Value Mapping` Functoid to the Address Destination node.

4) Next, you need to cater for non-existent Address 2's. So, add a Logical Not functoid to your mapper surface.

5) Connect the `Logical Not` to you `Logical Existence`. This reads "Not Exists".

6) Connect your `Logical Not` to Another `Value Mapping` Functoid as the First input.

7) Connect your Address 1 value to the `Value Mapping` functoid as your second input.

8) Connect the Second `Value Mapping` to the Address Destination.

So, you should have two connections to the destination node but only one path with be true, resulting in one mapping.

Hope this gives you a guide on how to approach this. Shout if you need more help!

EDIT:
Heres an illustration to help!

[image]

TJ

Comment: Hey b777, if that answered your question, please 'tick' the answer so we know that it is correct and teepeeboy gets the recognition in Rep points.